# Android graphics.Camera - how to set Location perpendicular to surface?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-graphics

android's class  import android.graphics.Camera has  a default location it uses. but there is a [method to change the camera's position](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html#setLocation(float,%20float,%20float)).

How can i adjust the camera's tilt such that it looks at the view perpendicular to the surface. sort of like looking from a air-plane onto the surface ?

Here is what i have attempted so  far:

```
mCamera.setLocation(0f,9f,0f)
```

but this does not  make the viewing angle perpendicular  to the ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to rotate the camera, I don't know this API but it seems that you have `rotate` [methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html#rotate(float,%20float,%20float) available.

I'd try a `mCamera.rotateX(90)` for a start.